# How to do rapid execution of for loop(Python) in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I am building a stock market trading tool using python. The broker comapny as of now published a python sdk, where we can develop a software using that.
The problem araises when I send a request to buy a share. Whenever an order is placed, I am getting an response as acknowledgement from the server, which takes any where from 0.8 to 1.2 seconds.

In my case, I willl place atleast 20 orders at a time, as per the above sequence, if I use a for loop for placing orders, it takes atleast 20 seconds to finish the loop. Actually I dont use the response which I get after placig the order, thus I dont want to wait for the response and need to execute all 20 orders at a time. I tried threads, Asyncio, concurrent futures.
All of them taking at least 5 seconds to finish a for loop with 20 iterations. If the iteration is less than 6, then using the threads gave the best result, ie orders got executed all ata time without any delay.
I kindly request some one to shed some light on this, how can I execute a for loop with 20 iterations all together without any delay.

This needs to be executed 20 times at a time:

```
client.place_order(exchange_segment = ExchangeSegment , product = Product, price = '45',
                   order_type = OrderType, quantity = quantity, validity = Validity,
                   trading_symbol = TradingSymbol, transaction_type = TransactionType,
                   tag = Tag, amo = AMO)
```

I tried the following methods,

Threads :

```
def placeorder(quantity):
            client.place_order(exchange_segment = ExchangeSegment , product = Product, price = '45',order_type = OrderType, quantity = quantity, validity = Validity,trading_symbol = TradingSymbol, transaction_type = TransactionType,tag = Tag, amo = AMO)
            
        quantity=[]  
        for i in range(20):
          quantity.append(str(800)) #mentioning the order quantitiy for each iteration in this list
            
        
        threads = []
        for i in range(20):
            t = threading.Thread(target=palceorder, args=(quantity[i],))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
```

Asyncio:

```
        quantity=[]  
        for i in range(20):
          quantity.append(str(800))
        def background(f):
            def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

            return wrapped

        @background
        def placeorder(quantity):
            client.place_order(exchange_segment = ExchangeSegment , product = Product, price = '45',order_type = OrderType, quantity = quantity, validity = Validity,trading_symbol = TradingSymbol, transaction_type = TransactionType,tag = Tag, amo = AMO)
        for i in quantity:
            placeorder(i)`
```

Concurrent futures:

```
def placeorder(quantity):
            client.place_order(exchange_segment = ExchangeSegment , product = Product, price = '45',order_type = OrderType, quantity = quantity, validity = Validity,trading_symbol = TradingSymbol, transaction_type = TransactionType,tag = Tag, amo = AMO)
quantity=[]  
for i in range(20):
   quantity.append(str(800))
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(15) as executor:
            executor.map(placeorder, quantity)
```

Comment: Your indentation is inconsistent and incorrect in your Threads code.

Comment: I have edited few indentation corrections, if it still lacks somewhere could you please help me correct it ?

Comment: And for what its worth to create your `quantity` list, you just need `quantity = ['800'] * 20`. You have so much code that accomplished so little.

Comment: @Booboo , Thanks for your comment. Yes brother, since I am learning the language just to code this tool, am a newbie and have to learn more for using the tricks and shortcuts in my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to ensure that you are submitting no more than 20 orders per second, then the following `RateLimiter` class could be used:

```py
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class RateLimiter:
    def __init__(self, call_count: int, period: float=1.0) -> None:
        self._call_count = int(call_count)
        self._period = float(period)
        self._called_timestamps = deque()
        self._lock = Lock()

    def throttle(self) -> None:
        with self._lock:
            while True:
                now = time.monotonic()
                while self._called_timestamps:
                    time_left = self._called_timestamps[0] + self._period - now
                    if time_left >= 0:
                        break
                    self._called_timestamps.popleft()
                if len(self._called_timestamps) < self._call_count:
                    break
                time.sleep(time_left)
            self._called_timestamps.append(now)


# 20 calls per second (or perhaps 20 calls per 1.1 second
# just to be safe):
rate_limiter = RateLimiter(20, 1.0)

def create_order(x: int) -> None:
    ... # arbitrary code to get things ready for the API call

    # Put this immediately before invoking the API:
    rate_limiter.throttle()
    # We would normally be calling an API to create an order,
    # but for demo purposes we just print x with the time:
    print(f'x = {x:2} at time {time.time()}')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(20) as executor:
    executor.map(create_order, range(42))
```

Prints:

```None
x =  0 at time 1700224533.0041072
x =  1 at time 1700224533.0041072
x =  2 at time 1700224533.0062273
x =  3 at time 1700224533.0062273
x =  5 at time 1700224533.0072248
x =  6 at time 1700224533.0082252
x =  4 at time 1700224533.0072248
x =  9 at time 1700224533.0082252
x = 10 at time 1700224533.0095797
x =  8 at time 1700224533.0082252
x = 13 at time 1700224533.0095797
x = 14 at time 1700224533.0105777
x = 11 at time 1700224533.0095797
x = 17 at time 1700224533.011574
x = 18 at time 1700224533.011574
x =  7 at time 1700224533.0082252
x = 16 at time 1700224533.011574
x = 12 at time 1700224533.0095797
x = 15 at time 1700224533.0105777
x = 19 at time 1700224533.011574
x = 20 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 21 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 23 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 24 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 26 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 28 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 22 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 31 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 33 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 25 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 29 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 32 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 27 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 30 at time 1700224534.011685
x = 34 at time 1700224534.026685
x = 35 at time 1700224534.026685
x = 37 at time 1700224534.026685
x = 39 at time 1700224534.026685
x = 38 at time 1700224534.026685
x = 36 at time 1700224534.026685
x = 40 at time 1700224535.025956
x = 41 at time 1700224535.025956
```